# load on click from an external li

Tags: php, jquery, load

This is my test.php page and I am trying to load in `<< id="new-nav" >>` the content of an external page.

The senario is as follows: I want to click the li from my menu which is in the `<?php include 'Menu/Side-menu.html.php'; ?>` and load the content in the test.php at the  `<< id="new-nav" >>` area

```
<div id="left"> 
<?php include 'Menu/Side-menu.html.php'; ?> 
</div> 

<div id="main"> 
<p>This is a test</p> 

<b>see the text:</b> 
<ol id="new-nav"></ol> 
</div> 

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $("#test li").click(function (e) { 

    // Stop the link from changing the page 
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // Your jQuery code. 
    $("#new-nav").load(('Menu/Side-menu.html.php').attr("href")); 
  }); 

}); 
</script>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to get with this code: ('Menu/Side-menu.html.php').attr("href") ???

Comment: I don't know what's inside of Menu/Side-menu.html.php but why are you php including it and then loading it via AJAX again in the same page?!

Comment: probably cause i don't know how else to do it, i have my menu include it so i can use to all my pages

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this solution instead:

```
 $("#test li").click(function (e) { 

    // Stop the link from changing the page 
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // Your jQuery code. 
    $.post('Menu/Side-menu.html.php',function(response) { // (added quotes)
         $("#new-nav").html(response);
    });
 });
```

Comment: I have unexpected token }

 $("#test li").click(function (e) { 

    // Stop the link from changing the page 
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // Your jQuery code. 
    $.post(Menu/Side-menu.html.php,function(response) {
         $("#new-nav").html(response);
    }
 });

Comment: add quotes around URL - 'Menu/Side-menu.html.php' and ");" after "}"

Comment: thanks oyatek, but still i have Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: thanks again , now its working , But the suggestion of Alessandro is loading my menu when i click and not the href

Comment: Come on people a little of help please, please

Comment: you can parse the response. you can store the response into a div hidden  $("#hidden.div").html(response); and after select the element that you want $("#new-nav").append($("#hidden.div").find(what you want));